# How to find certain percentage of colors in the image within a filter?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I use matlab R2010b.

I have a RGB image and two color triplets `c1=[a1 a2 a3]; c2=[b1 b2 b3]`. Using matlab, I want to find areas with radius 10px that has P1 percent of color `c1` and P2 percent of color `c2`.

What I came up with is creating a filter `f=fspecial('disk', 10);` and then manually iterating through the image and counting the values inside that disc. Is there any other way more elegant and fast?

Comment: What dou you mean with P1 percent of color `c1`. Should it be the exact color? What do you define as a mix of  `c1` and `c2`? Can you provide a sample image with the desired result? Can you provide us your current code?

Comment: @m7913d, I updated my post. I accidentally added "mix of c1 and c2". It doesn't have to be the exact color. It can be up to a certain threshold.

Answer (score 0):

**for a square of 10px by 10px (i have no idea for a disc)**

first create 2 separate filter  C1,C2 , after filtering the image with these 2 filters we have 2 matrices A1,A2 which their element consist of 1 or 0 (for A1 , 1 if the pixel rgb  is C1 else 0)
code for filter C1:(you must do this code for R and G and B and then merge the results)

```
A1R=Image_R;
A1R(A1R~=c1R)=0;
A1R(A1R~=0)=1;
% find similary for A1G and A1B
A1=A1R+A1G+A1B;
A1(A1~=3)=0;
A1(A1~0)=1;
% do the same to find A2
```

finally you want to find areas which sum of values in [A1,A2]=[P1,P2]

for a square of 10px by 10px we could write:(i have no idea for a disc):
(assuming that A1 and A2 are n-by-n matrices)

```
%creating a summation matrix! 
B1=A1;
for i=2:10 
    B1=B1+[zeros(n,i-1),A1(:,1:n-(i-1))];
end

D1=B1;
for i=2:10 
    D1=D1+[zeros(i-1,n);B1(1:n-(i-1),:)];
end
D1(D1~=p1)=0;
D1(D1~=0)=1;
%value of 1 in the D1 shows that selected region has P1 percent of color 1(c1)

E1=D1(10:n,10:n);

find E2 the same way 

H1=(E1+E2);
H1(H1~=2)=0;
H1(H1~=0)=1;
%value of one in H1 shows that selected region has P1 percent of c1 and P2   
%percent of c2 for example if H1(2,4)=1 then the region starting from (2,4) and 
%ends in (11,13) (from main image) is a desired region.
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not the best solution but it can speed up your code. Also, this will be helpful if P1 and P2 are either very small or very high.

First, don't deal with comparing each value one by one; create a mask for both c1 and c2.

```
[r,c,~] = size(im);
mask1 = zeros(r, c); 
mask2 = zeros(r, c); 

for i=1:r
    for j = 1:c  
        mask1(i,j) = all(impixel(im,i,j) == [a1 a2 a3]);
        mask2(i,j) = all(impixel(im,i,j) == [b1 b2 b3]);
    end
end
```

Secondly, the number of pixels in a circle = pi*10^10 = 314 and the diagonal of 7*7 < 10, so if you pick the center within a 7*7 block, all the pixels will be within the circle.

Split the image into blocks of 7*7, if a block contains more than P1 or P2 percent or less than 1-P1 or 1-P2 percent, then the center of the circle won't be in this block, so you can skip 49 correlations at a time.

For example, you want P1=10% and P2 = 5% which means max 31 pixels can be `col1=[a1 a2 a3]` in a circle and max 15-16 pixels can be equal to `col2=[b1 b2 b3]`

If a block contains more than 31 col1 or 15 col2, then you can skip the whole block as the center of the circle.

Of course, this is very much dependent to your data and selection of P1 and P2

Answer (score 0):

`fspecial('disk', 10)` gives you an averaging filter, which means if we set all the pixels that equal, say, `c1` to `1` and apply the filter, the value at each pixel will be the percentage of neighboring pixels equalling `c1`.

To create this image, we just have to create a logical matrix for each color channel and then combine them with logical `AND`. For a given image `Img`:

```
c1 = [a1 a2 a3];   % color to find
tol1 = [t1 t2 t3]; % tolerance for each color [a1 a2 a3] +/-
c1_img = (Img(:,:,1) >= a1-t1) & (Img(:,:,1) <= a1+t1) &
         (Img(:,:,2) >= a2-t2) & (Img(:,:,2) <= a2+t2) &
         (Img(:,:,3) >= a3-t3) & (Img(:,:,3) <= a3+53);
```

Now all we have to do is use `imfilter` to get the percentage for `c1`:

```
pct_c1 = imfilter(c1_img, f);
```

Repeat for `c2`.

To find the centers of areas with exactly `p1` percent of `c1` and `p2` percent of `c2`:

```
centers_c1c2 = (pct_c1 == p1) & (pct_c2 == p2);
```

Or you can use the same approach we used for generating `c1_img` to find percentages within some tolerance.